# json parsing using Json.net . write a merging logic with Json

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I have two XML files. say sample1 and sample2 as below:
I have a logic written for merging two XML docs in some way and the resultant XML is shown as below . I want the exact thing to be done for two Jsons. Please let me know how I can do that using Newtonsoft Json.

Sample1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Records345 count="1">
    <Record contentId="230408" modelId="34" modelGuid="4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432" FileId="191" parentFileId="0">
     <Field id="3972" guid="e9630a75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b" type="1">RMZ</Field>
     <Field id="8872" guid="7ead210f-e634-4be9-9f17-c8728bd5f187" type="1">0</Field>
    </Record>
    <Metadata>
        <FieldDefinitions>
            <FieldDefinition id="3972" guid="e9630a75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b" name="Company" alias="Company" />
            <FieldDefinition id="8872" guid="7ead210f-e634-4be9-9f17-c8728bd5f187" name="Total Products &amp; Services" alias="Total_Products" />
        </FieldDefinitions>
    </Metadata>
    <LevelCounts>
        <LevelCount id="44" guid="4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432" count="1" />
    </LevelCounts>
</Records345>
```

Sample2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Records34511 count="1" >
    <Record contentId="230408" modelId="34" modelGuid="4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432" FileId="191" parentFileId="0">
        <Field id="4444" guid="hj75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b" type="1">RMZ</Field>
        <Field id="6666" guid="rtyu-e634-4be9-9f17-c8728bd5f187" type="1">0</Field>
    </Record>
    <Metadata>
        <FieldDefinitions>
            <FieldDefinition id="4444" guid="hj75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b" name="Company" alias="Company" />
            <FieldDefinition id="6666" guid="rtyu-e634-4be9-9f17-c8728bd5f187" name="Total Products &amp; Services" alias="Total_Products" />
        </FieldDefinitions>
    </Metadata>
    <LevelCounts>
        <LevelCount id="44" guid="4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432" count="1" />
    </LevelCounts>
</Records34511>
```

ResultantXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Records345 count="1">
    <Record contentId="230408" modelId="34" modelGuid="4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432" FileId="191" parentFileId="0">
        <Field id="3972" guid="e9630a75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b" type="1">RMZ</Field>
        <Field id="8872" guid="7ead210f-e634-4be9-9f17-c8728bd5f187" type="1">0</Field>
    </Record>
    <Metadata>
        <FieldDefinitions>
            <FieldDefinition id="3972" guid="e9630a75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b" name="Company" alias="Company"/>
            <FieldDefinition id="8872" guid="7ead210f-e634-4be9-9f17-c8728bd5f187" name="Total Products &amp; Services" alias="Total_Products"/>
        </FieldDefinitions>
    </Metadata>
    <LevelCounts>
        <LevelCount id="44" guid="4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432" count="1"/>
    </LevelCounts>
    <Record contentId="230408" modelId="34" modelGuid="4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432" FileId="191" parentFileId="0">
        <Field id="4444" guid="hj75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b" type="1">RMZ</Field>
        <Field id="6666" guid="rtyu-e634-4be9-9f17-c8728bd5f187" type="1">0</Field>
    </Record>
    <Metadata>
        <FieldDefinitions>
            <FieldDefinition id="4444" guid="hj75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b" name="Company" alias="Company"/>
            <FieldDefinition id="6666" guid="rtyu-e634-4be9-9f17-c8728bd5f187" name="Total Products &amp; Services" alias="Total_Products"/>
        </FieldDefinitions>
    </Metadata>
    <LevelCounts>
        <LevelCount id="44" guid="4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432" count="1"/>
    </LevelCounts>
</Records345>
```

the logic for XML merging is as below:

`void process(IList sourceFiles)
        {

```
        if (sourceFiles == null || sourceFiles.Count <= 1)
            return sourceFiles;

        XDocument intialDocument = XDocument.Load(sourceFiles[0].OriginalString);
        if (intialDocument.Root == null)
            return null;

        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        if (intialDocument.Declaration != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(intialDocument.Declaration.Encoding))
            encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(intialDocument.Declaration.Encoding);


        string outputFileName = "somefile.xml");
        using (Stream combinedDocument = File.Create(outputFileName))
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(combinedDocument, new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = encoding, Indent = true }))
        {

            // Write out the root node
            writer.WriteStartElement(intialDocument.Root.Name.LocalName);
            foreach (XAttribute attribute in intialDocument.Root.Attributes())
                writer.WriteAttributeString(attribute.Name.LocalName, attribute.Value);


            // Write out all inner nodes of every document
            foreach (Uri sourceFile in sourceFiles)
            {

                XDocument sourceDocument = XDocument.Load(sourceFile.OriginalString);
                if (sourceDocument.Root != null)
                {
                    foreach (XNode xml in sourceDocument.Root.Nodes())
                        xml.WriteTo(writer);
                }
            }

            // Write out ending root node
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

    }`
```

Json1

```
                {
      "Records345": {
        "-count": "1",
        "Record": {
          "-contentId": "230408",
          "-levelId": "34",
          "-levelGuid": "4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432",
          "-moduleId": "191",
          "-parentId": "0",
          "Field": [
            {
              "-id": "8876",
              "-guid": "790b8d7a-9ec5-4e69-8806-6b6604e71a37",
              "-type": "1",
              "#text": "0"
            },
            {
              "-id": "8877",
              "-guid": "79e58dfd-6294-49ef-aacd-1c97d551a9fa",
              "-type": "1",
              "#text": "0"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
          "FieldDefinitions": {
            "FieldDefinition": [
              {
                "-id": "8876",
                "-guid": "790b8d7a-9ec5-4e69-8806-6b6604e71a37",
                "-name": "Total Factories",
                "-alias": "Total Assets"
              },
              {
                "-id": "8877",
                "-guid": "79e58dfd-6294-49ef-aacd-1c97d551a9fa",
                "-name": "Total Facilities",
                "-alias": "Total_Facilities"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "LevelCounts": {
          "LevelCount": {
            "-id": "44",
            "-guid": "4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432",
            "-count": "1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Json2:

```
        {
      "Records34511": {
        "-count": "1",
        "Record": {
          "-contentId": "230408",
          "-levelId": "34",
          "-levelGuid": "4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432",
          "-moduleId": "191",
          "-parentId": "0",
          "Field": [
            {
              "-id": "3972",
              "-guid": "e9630a75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b",
              "-type": "1",
              "#text": "RMZ"
            },
            {
              "-id": "8872",
              "-guid": "7ead210f-e634-4be9-9f17-c8728bd5f187",
              "-type": "1",
              "#text": "0"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
          "FieldDefinitions": {
            "FieldDefinition": [
              {
                "-id": "3972",
                "-guid": "e9630a75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b",
                "-name": "Company",
                "-alias": "Company"
              },
              {
                "-id": "8872",
                "-guid": "7ead210f-e634-4be9-9f17-c8728bd5f187",
                "-name": "Total Products & Services",
                "-alias": "Total_Products_Services"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "LevelCounts": {
          "LevelCount": {
            "-id": "44",
            "-guid": "4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432",
            "-count": "1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

resultant Json should be:

```
        {
      "Records345": {
        "-count": "1",
        "Record": [
          {
            "-contentId": "230408",
            "-levelId": "34",
            "-levelGuid": "4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432",
            "-moduleId": "191",
            "-parentId": "0",
            "Field": [
              {
                "-id": "8876",
                "-guid": "790b8d7a-9ec5-4e69-8806-6b6604e71a37",
                "-type": "1",
                "#text": "0"
              },
              {
                "-id": "8877",
                "-guid": "79e58dfd-6294-49ef-aacd-1c97d551a9fa",
                "-type": "1",
                "#text": "0"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "-contentId": "230408",
            "-levelId": "34",
            "-levelGuid": "4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432",
            "-moduleId": "191",
            "-parentId": "0",
            "Field": [
              {
                "-id": "3972",
                "-guid": "e9630a75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b",
                "-type": "1",
                "#text": "RMZ"
              },
              {
                "-id": "8872",
                "-guid": "7ead210f-e634-4be9-9f17-c8728bd5f187",
                "-type": "1",
                "#text": "0"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Metadata": [
          {
            "FieldDefinitions": {
              "FieldDefinition": [
                {
                  "-id": "8876",
                  "-guid": "790b8d7a-9ec5-4e69-8806-6b6604e71a37",
                  "-name": "Total Factories",
                  "-alias": "Total Assets"
                },
                {
                  "-id": "8877",
                  "-guid": "79e58dfd-6294-49ef-aacd-1c97d551a9fa",
                  "-name": "Total Facilities",
                  "-alias": "Total_Facilities"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "FieldDefinitions": {
              "FieldDefinition": [
                {
                  "-id": "3972",
                  "-guid": "e9630a75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b",
                  "-name": "Company",
                  "-alias": "Company"
                },
                {
                  "-id": "8872",
                  "-guid": "7ead210f-e634-4be9-9f17-c8728bd5f187",
                  "-name": "Total Products & Services",
                  "-alias": "Total_Products_Services"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "LevelCounts": [
          {
            "LevelCount": {
              "-id": "44",
              "-guid": "4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432",
              "-count": "1"
            }
          },
          {
            "LevelCount": {
              "-id": "44",
              "-guid": "4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432",
              "-count": "1"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: It would be more relevant if you added input json and expected output.

Comment: @PalleDue I posted now. Thanks in advance